# WebGL texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable error

Tags: webgl

I been getting a "texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering." error when loading a texture to an object in WebGL. I tried all of the suggestions on StackOverflow but none of them worked for me. I tried changing the image files to make the dimensions a power of 2 and tried different file formats (jpg, gif, png).

I can't tell if the image is the problem or something is happening in my code.

Fragment Shader:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;

void main(void) {
 gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
}
```

initShaders()

```
function initShaders() {
var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");


//Create the program, then attach and link 
shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

//Check for linker errors.
if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert("Could not initialise shaders");
}

//Attach shaderprogram to openGL context.
gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute);

shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
shaderProgram.samplerUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler");
}
```

Texture Load:

```
var sunTexture;

function initTexture() {

sunTexture = gl.createTexture();
sunTexture.image = new Image();

sunTexture.image.onload = function() {
    handleLoadedTexture(sunTexture)
}

sunTexture.image.src = "images/leaves.jpg";  
}

function handleLoadedTexture(texture) {
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
   gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
   gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
   gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}
```

drawScene() - Render and draw the object

```
var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
var pMatrix = mat4.create();

function drawScene() {

  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  mat4.perspective(pMatrix, 45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0);


  // Render the Sun
 mat4.identity(mvMatrix);  
 mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, 0, 0, -7.0);
 mat4.multiply(mvMatrix, mouseRotMatrix, mvMatrix);

 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sunVertexPositionBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, sunVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sunVertexTextureBuffer);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, sunVertexTextureBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

 gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, sunTexture);
 gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);


setMatrixUniforms();
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, sunVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
}
```

initBuffers() - Set up the data for the position and texture buffer

```
var sunVertexPositionBuffer; 
var sunVertexTextureBuffer;

function initBuffers() {

sunVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer(); 
sunVertexTextureBuffer = gl.createBuffer();


var sRadius = 4;
var slices = 25;
var stacks = 12; 
var sVertices = []; 
var count = 0;

for (t = 0 ; t < stacks ; t++ ) { 
  var phi1 = ((t)/stacks) * Math.PI;
  var phi2 = ((t+1)/stacks) * Math.PI;

for (p = 0 ; p < slices + 1; p++) { 
  var theta = ((p)/slices ) * 2 * Math.PI ; 
  var xVal = sRadius * Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(phi1);
  var yVal = sRadius * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi1);
  var zVal = sRadius * Math.cos(phi1);

  sVertices = sVertices.concat([xVal, yVal, zVal]);
  count++;

  var xVal = sRadius * Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(phi2);
  var yVal = sRadius * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi2);
  var zVal = sRadius * Math.cos(phi2);

  sVertices = sVertices.concat([xVal, yVal, zVal]);
  count++;
 }
}

 var textureCoords = [];

 for (t = 0; t < stacks; t++)   {
  var phi1 = ((t)/stacks);
  var phi2 = ((t+1)/stacks);

  for (p = 0; p < slices + 1; p++) {
      var theta = 1 - ( (p)/slices );

      textureCoords = textureCoords.concat([theta, phi1]);
      textureCoords = textureCoords.concat([theta, phi2]);
  }
 }      

 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sunVertexPositionBuffer);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(sVertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, sunVertexTextureBuffer);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);  

 sunVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3; 
 sunVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = count 
 sunVertexTextureBuffer.itemSize = 2;
 sunVertexTextureBuffer.numItems = stacks * (slices + 1) * 2;

 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
}
```

Comment: Did you try something like `sunTexture.image.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');` (right after `sunTexture.image = new Image();`)? Did you try to download a square, power of 2 test texture somewhere (google)?

Comment: I added that in just now and it didn't do anything. I been downloading textures from webGL tutorials and those don't work either.

Comment: Where do you define an array of generic vertex attribute data for `shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute`? Are `"uPMatrix"` and `"uMVMatrix"` proper initialized?

Comment: Do you draw the scene only once!? Or do you draw the scene continuously in a  render loop (what you should do)? Note, possibly the texture loading is delayed (`handleLoadedTexture`) and the texture is not loaded in the first frame.

Comment: The scenes are continuously loaded. I have a tick() function that calls on drawScene() for the render loop. I'll add the the rest of the drawScene() code and my initBuffers() method where I set up the data for the positions and textures.

Comment: I can't find any obvious issue in your code.

Comment: See [js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rabbid76/0fxmt342/)

Comment: After some more fooling around, removing the " mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, 0, 0, -7.0);" it is now displaying the texture but it blows up to the entire size of the screen.

Comment: Fixed. I had to add an animation function that rotated the sphere. Otherwise it didn't show.

Comment: Found the actual error. I wrote mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, 0, 0, -7.0) instead of mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [0, 0, -7.0]). I feel so dumb

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely that the code starts rendering before the images has loaded and until that time your texture is not-renderable.

My solution is always to start the texture with a single pixel so it's renderable immediately

```
 sunTexture = gl.createTexture();
 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, sunTexture);
 gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 1, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
               new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255])); // blue
```

When the image finishes loading the code will update the texture but until then it's usable.

See [these tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html)